# how to convert the Json Array from url into java array in order to display different country names?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

herein, i am using https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/lang/es in text2 and able to display just only the one country "Argentina" from the Jason array. However, i wants to display different country names.

```
try {
  JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(text2);
  String []fields = { "name","callingCodes","capital","region","population"};

    for (int i=0 ;i < fields.length; i++) {
    tv.append(fields[i] + " = " + jo.getString(fields[i]) + "\n");
       if (fields[i].equalsIgnoreCase("flag")) {

               Picasso.with(c)
                .load("https://media1.britannica.com/eb-media/54/69554-004-3E298C44.jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_android_temp)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .into(img);
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the text2 string as a JSONArray instead of JSONObject and iterate through the array. Something like this:

```
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(text2);
    String []fields = { "name","callingCodes","capital","region","population"};
    for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        for (int i=0 ;i < fields.length; i++) {
            tv.append(fields[i] + " = " + obj.getString(fields[i]) + "\n");

            if (fields[i].equalsIgnoreCase("flag")) {

               Picasso.with(c)
              .load("https://media1.britannica.com/eb-media/54/69554-004- 
               3E298C44.jpg")
              .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_android_temp)
              .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
              .into(img);
            }
         }
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: its showing error in foreach loop for jArray ...for (JSONObject obj : jArray) .

Comment: now its now picking up the data through JsonArray. as text2 is url. How ever it picks the data through Jsonobject

Answer (score 0):

Please try to iterate through JSON array that is jo in your case

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(text2);
            if(jsonArray!=null && jsonArray.length()>0){
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    //Process Json Here
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store that in JSONArray.

Loop your JSONArray and get JSONObject like

```
obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
name = obj.getString("name");
```

Get the name from the `obj` Object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Your Example Implement your code

```
 List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONArray itemArray=new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for (int i=0; i<itemArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject actor = itemArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = actor.getString("name");
        allNames.add(name);
    }
```

Comment: what is "abridged_cast"? is it is a json array or a particular name ?

Comment: Its a key of your json aaray

Comment: in my case i am using url and in url there is no key for json array

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do this work like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayString);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        list.add( jsonArray.getString(i) );
    }
```